# How do I call this function?

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm reading a lot about "typedef functions", but I getting casting errors when I try to call this one. What's the correct syntax to call this function?

```
typedef ::com::Type* Func(const char* c, int i);
```

Comment: There is no function here, so there's nothing to call. The statement defines `Func` as a type, not a function.

Comment: The syntax is invalid from what I understand. `typedef ::com::Type (*Func)(const char* c, int i);` would be closer to being valid.

Comment: @ahenderson: There's absolutely nothing invalid about this specific syntax. It is perfectly legal to define a typedef name for a *function* type (as opposed to *pointer to function* type) in C++ (and in C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no function in your code. There's only a type name `Func` that stands for function type. There's nothing to call there.

The name `Func`, as defined in your question, can be used in several different ways.

For example, you can use it to declare a function

```
Func foo;
```

The above is equivalent to declaring

```
::com::Type* foo(const char*, int);
```

This will also work for member function declarations. (However, you can't use it to *define* a function).

For another example, you can use it when declaring a pointer to a function, by adding an explicit `*`

```
Func *ptr = &some_other_function;
```

The above is equivalent to declaring

```
::com::Type* (*ptr)(const char*, int) = &some_other_function;
```

For yet another example, you can use it as a parameter type in another function

```
void bar(Func foo)
```

in which case the function type will automatically decay to function *pointer* type, meaning that the above declaration of `bar` is equivalent to

```
void bar(Func *foo)
```

and equivalent to

```
void bar(::com::Type* (*foo)(const char*, int));
```

And so on.

In other words, show us what your are trying to do with it. As is your question is too broad to be answered specifically.

Comment: I was just trying to understand somebody else code. Looks like it's missing an "implementation" (if I can call it this) for that function. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Tom Brito: Well, once again, what you have in your original post is not a function. It cannot have an "implementation". There's nothing to "implement" there. Your declaration declares a *type*, not a function. Types don't have "implementations".

Answer (score 4):

that statement makes `Func` a type. Then you'll have to say `Func *f = anotherFunc` given another func is defined as : `::com::Type* anotherFunc(const char *c, int i){ /*body*/ }`

Then you can call `f("hello", 0)` and it should work.

Comment: Yes you're right @AndreyT I must change that to `Func*` thanks a bunch :)

Comment: So there must be another function that implements it (your `anotherFunc`)? Becouse I've searched all the code for it, and looks like there isn't... :(

Answer (score 1):

**`typedef` function syntax:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

typedef int(*F)(int a, int b);

int main() {
    F f = add;
    cout  << f(1,2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**The break down of `typedef int(*F)(int a, int b);`**

- The `type` name is F in brackets
- Return type is the `int` at the beginning.
- The parameters are (int, int)

**Usage `F f = &add;`:**

- F is our type.
- f is the variable name.
- add is the function with the correct signature.

A valid syntax in your case would be: `typedef ::com::Type (*Func)(const char* c, int i);`

Comment: dont need &  ---> F f=add;

Comment: @qPCR4vir Nicely spotted. Removed.